# Условный оператор IF [NOT] не работает в bat файле

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть такой батник:

```
@echo off
@echo Please choose your target!
set /P target=""
if %target%=="" (
    set target="0"
)
@echo %target%
pause
```

При вводе какого-либо значения падает с непредвиденной ошибкой, а если сделать ввод пустым то говорит `Режим вывода команд на экран (ECHO) отключен.`, но не делает того что нужно. А должен ждать ввод в переменную `target`, и если ничего не ввели то присвоить переменной значение `0`, потом вывести ее значение. Что я неправильно сделал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере `not` похоже скопирован с документации, где квадратные скобки обозначают необязательность этого `not`, т.е. правильно писать `if not %target%==1 ...`.
Также, у вас идет сравнение с 1, хотя исходя из текста вопроса вам нужно значение по умолчанию, если пользователь не ввел ничего.
Знаки `@` после того как был выполнен `@echo off` уже не нужны (т.к. вывод выполняемых команд уже отключен).

Рабочий вариант:

```
@echo off
echo Please choose your target!
set target=""
set /P target=""
if %target%=="" (
    set target=0
)
echo %target%
pause
```

Перед запросом значения у пользователя (`set /P target=""`) переменная `target` устанавливается в `""`, т.к. если пользователь не будет вводить ничего, и нажмет сразу `ENTER`, то значение `target` не поменяется.

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает, в случае ввода пустоты. Говорит `непредвиденное появление set`

Comment: @sanu0074 вы имеете ввиду, что если просто нажать ENTER?

Comment: да, просто ничего не вводим

Comment: @sanu0074 затрудняюсь ответить, не могу воспроизвести у себя.

Comment: Обновил код батника в вопросе, у меня win7. Попробуйте запустить его у себя если не сложно

Comment: @sanu0074 добавьте `set target=""` перед запросом, похоже вы успели скопировать код из ответа до того как я его поправил.